# HQL: Max date of previous month

Tags: date, hive, max, hiveql

Good morning,
I have a problem I've been trying to solve for but am getting now where.

I need to find the max date of the previous month. Normally I would just use the following to find the last day of the previous month: last_day(add_months(current_date, -1)

However, this particular data set doesn't always have the last day with data. E.g. Last day in the data for May was May 30th. Obviously if i try using the syntax above it would return no data because it would be looking for 5/31.

So is there a way to find the "max" day available in the data of the previous month? Or the month prior etc.?

Comment: how the data looks like

Comment: i just need to return data with the most recent as of date for the previous month. Eg. May has 31 days, however data is only loaded up until 5/30. Looking for a syntax that will find the max date for the "as_of_date" for the previous month.

Answer (score 0):

For example like this (two scans of table: one in subquery to find max date and one in main query):

```
select * 
  from mytable
where as_of_date in (select max(as_of_date) from mytable where as_of_date between first_day(add_months(current_date, -1)) and  last_day(add_months(current_date, -1))
```

Or (single scan + analytic function) like this

```
select col1 ... colN
from
(
     select t.*, rank() over (partition by month (t.as_of_date) order by t.as_of_date desc) rnk
      from mytable t 
     where --If you have partition on date, this WHERE may improve performance 
          t.as_of_date between first_day(add_months(current_date, -1)) and  last_day(add_months(current_date, -1))
)s 
where rnk=1
```

Comment: thank you @leftjoin. I tried the first example but no results. I receive a log in sas but no errors are listed. 

WHERE as_of_date in (select max(as_of_date) from LSTable where as_of_date between first_day(add_months(current_date, -1) and  last_day(add_months(current_date, -1)

Comment: perhaps there were parenthesis missing? Change it to the following and now receive and error -  WHERE as_of_date in (select max(as_of_date) from lnp_loanservicing where as_of_date between first_day(add_months(current_date, -1)) and  last_day(add_months(current_date, -1)))

Comment: Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'as_of_date': Correlating expression cannot contain unqualified 
       column references.

Comment: @user1590497 indeed there is parenthesis missing, fixed. not tested :)

Comment: thank you. Again, no results in sas but no error log. There is an exclamation (!) beside the line of code though.